# My list is not thread safe even though I lock it

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, locking, synchronization

I am getting:

"collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute" at this lline:

```
foreach (Message msg in queue)
```

after a while.

**I have to use .NET 2.0.**

The two operations I make on the private List<> named "queue" are as follows:

```
// 1st function calls this
lock (queue)
{
      queue.Add(msg);
}

// 2nd function calls this
lock (queue)
{
      using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("path", true)
      {
             foreach (Message msg in queue) // This is were I get the exception after a while)
             {
                  outfile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg)); 
             }

              queue = new List<Message>();
      }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong but why don't you simply call queue.Clear() instead of allocating a new one? It's the only _issue_ I see even if I can't imagine what may go wrong.

Comment: a: are there **any** other operations that talk to `queue`, and b: why do you reassign `queue`?

Comment: I agree with both comments, it seems like it may be undefined behavior if you reassign the queue before releasing its lock.

Comment: oh no. that's an O(n) vs an O(1). I certainly don't want that since I don't mind what happens to any item I've already iterated.

Comment: @Brady actually that is defined: the old value is unlocked

Comment: Before the 2nd lock  is called I have:

if (queue == null || queue.Count == 0)
   continue;

Comment: @gStation well, you shouldn't *really* access `.Count` outside the lock, but it is unlikely to hurt you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the parameter which is used by the lick statement should be readonly. See this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lock)

Use `readonly private object` instead of `queqe`

Code should be

```
eadonly object _object = new object();
// 1st function calls this
lock (_object)
{
      queue.Add(msg);
}

// 2nd function calls this
lock (_object)
{
      using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("path", true)
      {
             foreach (Message msg in queue) // This is were I get the exception after a while)
             {
                  outfile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg)); 
             }

              queue = new List<Message>();
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be - I don't disagree: however, can you illustrate a race scenario where it actually breaks here? I'm not sure I can. I'd rather check for other uses of the list first, personally.

Comment: It works because you do not lock on the queue not because of readonly. See @MarcGravell comments. About Clear() performances: if they're a problem (after a JSON serialization?) then maybe you do not would even use a lock...

Comment: @Adriano I understand that its because the lock is made on a different object (which by using readonly, you make sure it isn't changed).

The json serialization is obviously not easy on performance, but it's currently a given for me.
I'm hoping to get time to create a better log mechanism for that.

Comment: @gStation making readonly an object you do not make it **constant** (I miss this feature from C++), you just prevent the variable to be reassigned (you can even declare your list readonly). Moreover isn't mandatory to use the lock with a read-only object (but to do it saves you from this situation, simply replace the assignment with Clear() and you'll solve without any other change). The sentence about performance was intended as comment against the use of Clear() :)

Comment: @gStation as long as the queue is small, then frankly it doesn't matter whether it is O(1) or O(n). Or alternatively, **don't use a list to represent a queue** - use a *queue*.

Comment: @gStation sorry, I can't understand. You're writing to **disk**. Using a **foreach**. **Serializing** in JSON. Using a **lock**. Storing data in a **List** (instead of a Queue or a ConcurrentQueue, even if self implemented). Do you care about the performance of Clear()? The foreach overhead will consume more CPU than the Clear!!!

Answer (score 3):

(below; well, I can't come up with a race condition that would cause this... but: who knows...)

<s>Firstly, you **really** need to look for some other code that talks to the list; the problem is not in the code you post. How do I know this? Because at the point you are enumerating (`foreach (Message msg in queue)`), you have a lock on `queue`, and we haven't done anything with the (very dodgy, but unrelated) re-assignment of the lock object.</s>

For this `foreach` to error means that **something else** is mutating the list. First thing to do, very simply, is to rename the list field. This will very quickly show you if some other code touches the list. Also check that you never **expose** the list outside this code, i.e. never `return queue;` from anywhere.

The problem **does not appear to be in the code you show**. Reassigning the lock object is bad practice and you shouldn't do that - but: I can't see a scenario (with the code shown) where it would actually *break* it.

---

Lists are not the best model here, and reassigning a lock object is **not** a good idea. *If only there was an inbuilt type designed to represent a queue*...

```
private readonly Queue<Message> queue = new Queue<Message>();
...
lock (queue) {
    queue.Enqueue(msg);
}

// 2nd function calls this
lock (queue) {
    if(queue.Count == 0) continue; // taken from comments

    using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("path", true) {
        while(queue.Count != 0) {
            Message msg = queue.Dequeue();
            outfile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg)); 
        }
    }
}
```

no need to clear, since `Dequeue` does that intrinsically and efficiently.

Comment: I swear - nothing in my codes touched queue other then what I written (did you noticed the comment?)
Using the readonly object as the lock flag fixed the problem.

Comment: @gStation well, I'm genuinely surprised. I can't come up with that race myself, but: threading is always crazy ;p

Comment: That is very weird.
This: "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" is an external tool which I don't know how its implemented. Could it be that it does some memory management that risks the List safety?

Comment: If I can Enqueue and Dequeue the readonly queue, then I apparently don't understand the effect of readonly on a collection - care to explain that?

Comment: @gStation the readonly just stops you reassigning the field to a **different** queue - which would make it very confusing to reason what object is being locked at any time ;p